# .bat file xcopy based on operating system

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I'm having trouble creating a .bat file to do the following;

```
IF OS xp
run xcopy

IF OS Win 7 
run xcopy

Else
exit
```

To keep it simple I would like to the use `IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\." THEN windows 7`

Can anyone please help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212033/get-windows-version-in-a-batch-file.  use the output to branch accordingly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the batch you've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('ver') do set ver=%%a
set Version=
for %%a in (95=95 98=98 ME=ME NT=NT 2000=2000 5.1.=XP 5.2.=2003 6.0.=Vista 6.1.=7 6.2.=8) do (
   if "!Version!" equ "this" (
      set "Version=%%a"
   ) else if "!ver: %%a=!" neq "%ver%" (
      set Version=this
   )
)
goto:_%version% 2>nul || goto:eof

:_xp
:_7
xcopy /?
```

© [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) at [dostips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=24771#p24771)